# Flask Blueprints Import Model

Tags: python, flask

I want to make a flask blueprint and I want to use a model from the main app. My Blueprints work but when I import the model from the main app then I have an error.

Blueprint

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request,Blueprint
import datetime
from app import Users,Posts
second = Blueprint("second",__name__,template_folder='templates')
@second.route("/posts3")
def posts3():
    allposts = Post.query.all()
    if len(allposts) < 60:
        return redirect('/posts')
    else:
        return render_template('allposts3.html',posts=allposts[60:])
    return render_template('allposts.html')
```

Main

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from second import second
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQAlchemy(app)
class Users(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    missions = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=True)
    waiter = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post',backref='user')
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text,unique=False,nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    author = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'),unique=False)

#I skipped some code
db.create_all()
app.register_blueprint(second)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Python File\app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from second import second
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Python File\second.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import hello
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Python File\app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from second import second
ImportError: cannot import name 'second' from partially initialized module 'second' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\user\Desktop\Python File\second.py)
```

How can I import the models?

Thanks.

Comment: The error generally comes when your working file has the same name as module and those modules depend on each other. Give the complete code with file names. It should be an easy fix.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you have any answer?

Comment: A solution I use is defining my models in a separate file called `models.py`. I can then access these models in my blueprints with `from app.models import Users, Posts`.

Answer (score 0):

its because you are importing from "app.py" file to "second.py" and vice versa. Thats causing a circular import. I would recommend following the factory pattern for your application structure:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/appfactories/

It can get really annoying to deal with circular imports, if you dont!

Comment: Can you write an answer please?

Comment: I think you should do some reading about the factory pattern. There are good tutorials out there. Just follow one of them, for example https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-application-factory/